# How to detach HBITMAP from GDI+ Bitmap?

Tags: c++, gdi+, hbitmap

I'm trying to create an `HBITMAP` from a GDI+ `Bitmap`, and whilst this works, as soon as the `Bitmap` goes out of scope the `HBITMAP` become invalid, too.

How can I detach the `HBITMAP` from the original GDI+ `Bitmap`, so that I'm free to move the `HBITMAP` around in my program?

The method currently looks like:

```
HBITMAP GDIBITMAPToHBitmap()
{
   int width = 500;
   int height = 500;

   //Create a bitmap
   Bitmap myBitmap(width, height, PixelFormat32bppRGB);
   Graphics g(&myBitmap);
   Gdiplus::Pen blackpen(Color(255, 0, 0, 0), 3);

   // Perform some drawing operations here

   HBITMAP myHbitmap;
   Gdiplus::Status status = myBitmap.GetHBITMAP(Color(255, 255, 255), &myHbitmap);
   return myHbitmap; // Goes out of scope on return 
}
```

Comment: *How can I detach the HBITMAP from the original gdiplus bitmap?* -- Maybe redesign your code so that all of this is encapsulated in an object that *you* control the lifetime of?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If only it were that simple I'd have done that already!, hence I'm asking the question, if there is a way to detach, such as `CImage` supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much trial and error, I've found a solution that works. I don't know why, but at least it works.

I've found that the behaviour of `GetHBITMAP()` differs based on the original GDI+ `Bitmap` constructor that is called:

- if `Bitmap myBitmap(width, height, PixelFormat32bppRGB);` is called, the resulting `HBITMAP` will be invalidated when `myBitmap` goes out of scope.
- if using the constructor `Bitmap myBitmap(tempHbitmap, nullptr);` then the resulting `HBITMAP` remains valid, even after `myBitmap` is destroyed.

So, the resulting function now looks like:

```
HBITMAP GDIBITMAPToHBitmap(HBITMAP tempHbitmap)
{
   int width = 500;
   int height = 500;

   //Create a bitmap
   // Bitmap myBitmap(width, height, PixelFormat32bppRGB); Previously using
   Bitmap myBitmap(tempHbitmap, nullptr); // Now using

   Graphics g(&myBitmap);
   Gdiplus::Pen blackpen(Color(255, 0, 0, 0), 3);

   // Perform some drawing operations here
   g.DrawLine(&blackpen, (INT)0, 0, 250, 250);

   HBITMAP myHbitmap;
   Gdiplus::Status status = myBitmap.GetHBITMAP(Color(255, 255, 255), &myHbitmap);
   return myHbitmap; // HBITMAP no longer goes out of scope! 
}
```

Using this method, I'm the owner of both `HBITMAP`s - the temporary `tempHbitmap` that is passed into the function, and the returned `myHbitmap`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, This is what I thought would happen, however this doesn't seem to be the case, in the example in my answer, `tempHbitmap` remains a blank image, and `myHbitmap` has the expected drawing. They both have different addresses. When I tried your suggestion of returning `tempHbitmap`, I only get a blank image. It would seem that GetBitmap() has created a new `HBITMAP`.